Paper rejected because it did not fit the scope of a journal
I recently finished my paper and I submitted it to a journal. A few days later, I got a response from the editor saying that my manuscript had been rejected because it did not fit the scope of the journal, even if I believe it fitted (same references, similar articles). I submitted the paper again to another journal with similar aims and scope and the editor's decision was again rejection.
However, he suggested four journals suitable to transfer my article to and asked me to choose one of them. I agreed and resubmitted my article to one of the journals the editor suggested. It was rejected again yesterday as it did not fit the scope of the journal the editor suggested as suitable. Once again the new editor suggested journals suitable to transfer my article to and asked me to choose one of them, and so on.
What could be going on? I began to believe there are no proper reviewers and not proper scope.

Do you have experience writing papers? Do you have a coauthor who has experience writing papers? It's possible your paper is just very very bad or crank-y and "out of scope" is the editors' attempts to be polite.

@BryanKrause Certainly a possibility, but if they suggested it go to other journals, that seems less likely?

I agree with BryanKrause, as Editors referred that my manuscript was well written and provides valuable insights is , but was
considered to be out of scope for their  journal. I have experience writing papers. I' m also a reviewer.

It is likely your general topic is "in scope", but your actual findings do not rise to the level of impact of those papers to which yours is similar. I'll use an example from my line of work in materials science. There are lots of articles published regularly in the journal Advanced Materials (IF = 29) on battery materials. There are also lots of articles published on battery materials in MDPI and Hindawi journals (much much lower IF and reputation). Just because you are in the "topical scope" of the journal, it doesn't mean the findings themselves are within the "impact scope".

Thank you R1NaNo. The scope of impact of a journal is not always clear, that's why  I first check the aims and scope.
The point is that, as I mentioned above, that I submitted the article to journals with similar publications and bibliography, i.e.relevant to a similar audience, so it will have a similar impact. So I wonder if it is a matter of lack of appropriate reviewers for the subject of my article, which is about construction of a research tool.

Also, the paradox of the case that makes me wonder is that my article was rejected because it didi not fit to a journal that another journal transferred it to this as more relevant.

@Daniel Hatton. I have already submitted to three journals, and I still can't yet find out what they mean by saying that my article is well-written and interesting but out of their scope. I believe that editors should state the exact reason that an article is rejected without review and not have the authors look for it or imagine it.

We can definitely exclude a lack of appropriate reviewers because you wrote this in your description:

I recently finished my paper and I submitted it to a journal. A few days later, I got a response from the editor saying that my manuscript had been rejected because it did not fit the scope of the journal ...

No editor is going to give up on finding reviewers within a few days. In fact, it's very common that eventually-published papers still have no reviewers after this time.
You're encountering consistent desk rejections across all journals, including those that are supposedly within scope. That's a sign something is very wrong with your paper. It's not a problem with the journals, the editors, the reviewers, etc. It's a problem with your paper.*
Note "out of scope" or "not appropriate for journal" can be the editor's response for very very bad papers (see examples from John Mandblaur's angular-momentum-is-not-conserved papers, which fall within the realm of crankery). If you can't tell what's wrong, then you should get help from a published academic whom you trust to help diagnose what's wrong.

*It's also possible that it's a problem with you, if you've e.g. done things that got you blacklisted by most journals.

@AllureThank you for the comments. However, my article was neither poorly written nor outside the scope of the journals. As well, I have never caused any problems with any journal, as you wrongly assumed. My article was already recommended three times by the editors to be published in other journals with the same scope. If it was badly written, why did no editor mention it until now? Do you finally mean that it is so difficult for some editors to tell the truth to the authors about the reason for rejection, and they respond to everybody in the same "out of scope" manner?

@AllureAlso, as I mentioned in my initial post, the paradox is that my article was rejected as "out of scope" by a journal that another journal transferred it to as more relevant...

It is also understandable that if the paper falls into the realm of crankery, or badly written, Mr @Nik should have received such feedback from those editors. My idea is that, the problem was indeed the paper itself, however, it wasn't due to being not well written or being crank-y. I believe those journals have target readerships and the paper probably is too hard to comprehend for the reader, aka prioritize accessibility

@Nik Without having seen the paper, I cannot comment. Can you share the paper?

@DuyVăn I think most academics/editors feel that engaging with the authors of crank papers is not worth it, which is why they just brush off the paper without calling it crankery (see the link in answer).

@Allure. Thank you for the suggestion to see the paper but I don't have the approval of all the co-authors to send it to you. But I promise that when it is published, I will send it to you so that you can verify that it was both well-written and useful to the scientific community.

@DuyVăn. I agree that If a research or a paper is of good quality, then it may be suitable to be transferred to another journal, more relevant.  The paradox is that my article was rejected as "out of scope" by a journal that another journal transferred it to as more relevant...

@Niki Transferring to another journal is not a guarantee of on-topicness. But yes, it sounds frustrating.
